# CSV Formating with AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have a script that is suppose to run `autorep -j <Job Name> -q` and fetch the output of the previous command and filter it out to create a `CSV file`.

The Script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
read -p "Enter /DIR/PATH/FILENAME where you wish to copy the data: " FILENAME
echo "Enter the JOB_NAME or %SEARCHSTRING%"

while read -r i;
do
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            print "\"insert_job\",\"job_type\",\"command\",\"machine\",\"owner\",\"date_conditions\",\"condition\",\"run_calendar\",\"exclude_calendar\",\"days_of_week\",\"run_window\",\"start_times\",\"start_mins\",\"profile\",\"term_run_time\",\"watch_file\",\"watch_interval\""
        }
        /^insert_job:/ { jn="\""$2"\""; jt="\""$4"\""; cmd="\" \""; mcn="\" \""; own="\" \""; dc="\" \""; c="\" \""; rc="\" \""; ec="\" \""; dow="\" \""; ruw="\" \""; st="\" \""; sm="\" \""; prof="\" \""; trt="\" \""; wf="\" \""; wi="\" \"" }
        /^command:/ {cmd="\""$ "\""}
        /^machine:/ {mcn="\""$2"\""}
        /^owner:/ {own="\""$2"\""}
        /^date_conditions:/ {dc="\""$2"\""}
        /^condition:/ {c="\""$2"\""}
        /^run_calendar:/ {rc="\""$2"\""}
        /^exclude_calendar:/ {ec="\""$2"\""}
        /^days_of_week:/ {dow="\""$2"\""}
        /^run_window:/ {ruw="\""$2"\""}
        /^start_times:/ {gsub("\"",""); st="\""$2"\""}
        /^start_mins:/ {sm="\""$2"\""}
        /^profile:/ {prof="\""$2"\""}
        /^term_run_time:/ {trt="\""$2"\""}
        /^watch_file:/ {wf="\""$2"\""}
        /^watch_interval:/ {wi="\""$2"\""}
        /_if_terminated/{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", jn, jt, cmd, mcn, own, dc, c, rc, ec, dow, ruw, st, sm, prof, trt, wf, wi}
    ' < <(autorep -j $i -q) > $FILENAME.csv

    break
done
```

Depending of the type of job, the output of `autorep` command can be little different

Output of `Autorep -j <Job Name> -q`

**JOB_A**

```
insert_job: JOB_A   job_type: FW
machine: machine.server.com
owner: User
permission:
date_conditions: 0
term_run_time: 3
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/tmp/.profile"
alarm_if_terminated: 1
watch_file: "/tmp/Control*"
watch_interval: 60
```

**JOB_B**

```
insert_job: JOB_B   job_type: CMD
command: Autorep -M ALL
machine: machine.server.com
owner: User
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_mins: 9,19,29,39,49,59
run_window: "06:00-19:00"
std_out_file: "/tmp/JOB_B.out.txt"
std_err_file: "/tmp/JOB_B.err.txt"
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1
```

If i run the above script to get the output in a CSV format then i get the below output:

Script run for **JOB_A**

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_A","FW"," ","machine.server.com","User","0"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",""/tmp/.profile"","3"," "," "
```

Script run got **JOB_B**

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_B","CMD","command: Autorep -M ALL,"machine.server.com","User","1"," "," "," ","mo,tu,we,th,fr",""06:00-19:00""," ","9,19,29,39,49,59"," "," "," "," "
```

For JOB_A few of the fields are not even captured and for JOB_B Command and Machine come as one entity

**Expected Output:**

JOB_A

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_A","FW"," ","machine.server.com","User","0"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",""/tmp/.profile"","3",""/tmp/Control*"","60"
```

JOB_B

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_B","CMD","Autorep -M ALL","machine.server.com","User","1"," "," "," ","mo,tu,we,th,fr",""06:00-19:00""," ","9,19,29,39,49,59"," "," "," "," "
```

Comment: You rwant all those empty fields represented by a string with a single space?

Comment: Yes, if any of the job doesnt have any field in its definition then the CSV file shouldkeep it empty...

Comment: please update the question to show the explicit/expected output for `JOB A / JOB_A`

Comment: Its already there in the end of the question

Comment: for `JOB A / JOB_A` you've stated the expected output is: *`It should fetch all the fields that is required by the script`* ... which doesn't tell us the *actual* output; if the script is generating the correct output for `JOB A / JOB_A` then say that; if the script is generating the wrong output then show the actual/expected output

Comment: @markp-fuso i have updated the expected output for both jobs

Comment: Unless you're set on awk, my go-to for CSV processing on the command line is actually PHP: `php -r 'array_shift($argv);fputcsv(STDOUT, $argv);' foo bar baz`.

Comment: I showed you a much better approach than all those regexps and variables in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819310/1745001) by first creating an array that maps every tag (name) to it's value. You should really take another look at that and ask questions if you didn't understand any part of it.

Comment: `""/tmp/.profile""` in your current expected output isn't valid CSV btw - it should either be `/tmp/.profile` or `"/tmp/.profile"` or `"""/tmp/.profile"""`. Same for `""/tmp/Control*""`.

Comment: "if any of the job doesnt have any field in its definition then the CSV file shouldkeep it empty" -- pedantically `" "` is not empty, it is a one-character string. `""` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing *just* OP's current code ... there are two main issues:

- `/^command:/ {cmd="\""$ "\""}` - does not reference a specific field so `$` is treated the same as `$0` (the whole line), hence the reason the output for `JOB B / JOB_B` shows the whole line, ie, `command: Autorep -M ALL`; one solution would be to strip off the first field (plus the field delimiter) before referencing `$0`
- `/if_terminated/ { printf ...}` - is coded with an assumption the line containing `if_terminated` is the *last* line in the file, but for `JOB A / JOB_A` said line is *not* the last line so the `printf` is being run before all input lines have been processed; one solution would be to delay the `printf` until after the entire file has been read (eg, move to an `END{}` block)

Rolling these changes into OP's current `awk` code, and adding some formatting to make easier to read:

```
awk '
BEGIN                   { print "\"insert_job\",\"job_type\",\"command\",\"machine\",\"owner\",\"date_conditions\",\"condition\",\"run_calendar\",\"exclude_calendar\",\"days_of_week\",\"run_window\",\"start_times\",\"start_mins\",\"profile\",\"term_run_time\",\"watch_file\",\"watch_interval\"" }

/^insert_job:/          { jn="\""$2"\""; jt="\""$4"\""; cmd="\" \""; mcn="\" \""; own="\" \""; dc="\" \""; c="\" \""; rc="\" \""; ec="\" \""; dow="\" \""; ruw="\" \""; st="\" \""; sm="\" \""; prof="\" \""; trt="\" \""; wf="\" \""; wi="\" \"" }

/^command:/             {                   $0=substr($0,index($0,$2));
                           cmd="\""$0"\"" }
/^machine:/             {  mcn="\""$2"\"" }
/^owner:/               {  own="\""$2"\"" }
/^date_conditions:/     {   dc="\""$2"\"" }
/^condition:/           {    c="\""$2"\"" }
/^run_calendar:/        {   rc="\""$2"\"" }
/^exclude_calendar:/    {   ec="\""$2"\"" }
/^days_of_week:/        {  dow="\""$2"\"" }
/^run_window:/          {  ruw="\""$2"\"" }
/^start_times:/         {                   gsub("\"","");
                            st="\""$2"\"" }
/^start_mins:/          {   sm="\""$2"\"" }
/^profile:/             { prof="\""$2"\"" }
/^term_run_time:/       {  trt="\""$2"\"" }
/^watch_file:/          {   wf="\""$2"\"" }
/^watch_interval:/      {   wi="\""$2"\"" }

END                     { printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
                                 jn, jt, cmd, mcn, own, dc, c, rc, ec, dow, ruw, st, sm, prof, trt, wf, wi
                        }
'
```

Running this against the 2 input files generates:

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_A","FW"," ","machine.server.com","User","0"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",""/tmp/.profile"","3",""/tmp/Control*"","60"

"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_B","CMD","Autorep -M ALL","machine.server.com","User","1"," "," "," ","mo,tu,we,th,fr",""06:00-19:00""," ","9,19,29,39,49,59"," "," "," "," "
```

---

A third issue (ok, more of a nag) with the current code, which doesn't actually affect the output, is the unnecessary use of `while/break`; one alternative:

```
read -r i
awk '....' < <(autorep -j $i -q) > $FILENAME.csv
```

Comment: I am getting Syntax error for the above coe:

`awk: cmd. line:25:                                  jn, jt, cmd, mcn, own, dc, c, rc, ec, dow, ruw, st, sm, prof, trt, wf, wi printf "dbg2:" wf ":"
awk: cmd. line:25:                                                                                                            ^ syntax error`

its for the  wi print "dbg2:" wf ":" in the end

Comment: Also if i substitute the value of `$i` as a search string like `JOB%` then it doesnt fetch for results for all the jobs which the search string points to

Comment: @NecroCoder apologies, I cut-n-pasted the wrong set of code; I've updated so syntax errors should be addressed

Comment: @NecroCoder ; not sure I understand your 2nd comment; are you talking about running `autorep` with a wildcard that returns multiple jobs? if so, that's not described in your question and while you could update the question to address multiple jobs that would negate some of the answers you've already received; in this case I'd suggest upvoting and/or accepting any of the current answers that address the current question, see if you can modify the answers to address your multiple job requirement, and if you have issues then ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you choose `FS` properly then you can process the input smoothly:

```bash
awk -F ': | {2,}' -v OFS=',' '
    BEGIN {
        nf = split("insert_job,job_type,command,machine,owner,date_conditions,condition,run_calendar,exclude_calendar,days_of_week,run_window,start_times,start_mins,profile,term_run_time,watch_file,watch_interval",header,OFS)
        for (i = 1; i <= nf; i++)
            printf "%s%s", csvescape(header[i]), (i < nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    {
        for ( i = 1; i < NF; i += 2 )
            record[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    END {
        for ( i = 1; i <= nf; i++ )
            printf "%s%s", csvescape(record[header[i]]), (i < nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    function csvescape(str) {
        gsub(/"/,"\"\"",str)
        return "\"" str "\""
    }
'
```

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_A","FW","","machine.server.com","User","0","","","","","","","","""/tmp/.profile""","3","""/tmp/Control*""","60"
```

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_B","CMD","Autorep -M ALL","machine.server.com","User","1","","","","mo,tu,we,th,fr","""06:00-19:00""","","9,19,29,39,49,59","","","",""
```

**remarks:**

- The output isn't exactly the expected one but it is a **valid** CSV
- If you really need to output `" "` for the empty fields then you can add the code for it in the `csvescape` function.

Answer (score 0):

I see some of the field names that **are not coded for recognition** and capture.  You should report those if encountered for later review and consideration.

It is bad practice to code the **end-of-line semi-colon** ";" up against the last variable or character on a line, because it could be interpreted as part of that adjacent string.

I also see the line for command

```
/^command:/ {cmd="\""$ "\""}
```

might have the **missing digit "2"**.

Your logic for "**start_times**" will not capture the correct value.

It is not necessary to wrap field contents in a CSV with double quotes, unless there are special characters that confuse the field separator identification, i.e. the commas in "**start_mins**".
Unless you know that the process using the CSV files has issues with consecutive commas (i.e. "**,,**"), you should not have to assign the space character as a value for **"empty" fields**.  Also assigning spaces can be problematic for interpretation by some processes, so you might want to code with a specific value (I suggest the string "**NULL**" for visibility) or leave the value empty, i.e. 2 consecutive commas.

Lastly, if any of the fields contain your **delimiter character** (i.e. ",") then that could create confusion for some interpreters.  By definition, some might completely ignore the quotes ... and that would be problematic for parsing content like "**start_mins**".  In those cases, you need to allow for character substitution to eliminate the conflict.  In the code below, I have defined the **vertical bar "|"** as the alternate character to be used if a conflict is detected between the intended delimiter and the content being parsed.

```
#!/bin/bash

DBG=0

NOVAL="BL"
DQ=0
SPLITTER="|"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --null )
            NOVAL="NL" ; shift
            ;;
        --space )
            NOVAL="SP" ; shift
            ;;
        --empty )
            NOVAL="BL" ; shift
            ;;
        --quotes )
            DQ=1 ; shift
            ;;
        --splitter )
            SPLITTER="$2" ; shift ; shift
            ;;
        * )
            echo "\n\t Invalid parameter '$1' used on command line.  Only valid: [ --null | --space | --empty | --quotes ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

### Questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74867891/csv-formating-with-awk

cat >JOB_A <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
insert_job: JOB_A   job_type: FW
machine: machine.server.com
owner: User
permission:
date_conditions: 0
term_run_time: 3
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/tmp/.profile"
alarm_if_terminated: 1
watch_file: "/tmp/Control*"
watch_interval: 60
EnDoFiNpUt

cat >JOB_B <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
insert_job: JOB_B   job_type: CMD
command: Autorep -M ALL
machine: machine.server.com
owner: User
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_mins: 9,19,29,39,49,59
run_window: "06:00-19:00"
std_out_file: "/tmp/JOB_B.out.txt"
std_err_file: "/tmp/JOB_B.err.txt"
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1
EnDoFiNpUt

if [ ${DBG} -eq 1 ]
then
    wc -l JOB_A
    wc -l JOB_B
fi

#read -p "Enter /DIR/PATH/FILENAME where you wish to copy the data: " DESTINATION

if [ ${DQ} -eq 1 ]
then
    HEADER="\"insert_job\",\"job_type\",\"command\",\"machine\",\"owner\",\"date_conditions\",\"condition\",\"run_calendar\",\"exclude_calendar\",\"days_of_week\",\"run_window\",\"start_times\",\"start_mins\",\"profile\",\"term_run_time\",\"watch_file\",\"watch_interval\""

    FORMAT="\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n"
else
    HEADER="insert_job,job_type,command,machine,owner,date_conditions,condition,run_calendar,exclude_calendar,days_of_week,run_window,start_times,start_mins,profile,term_run_time,watch_file,watch_interval"
    FORMAT="%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"
fi

for job in JOB_A JOB_B
do
    DESTINATION="DUMP__${job}"
    echo -e "Processing: ${job} ..."
    #read -p "Enter the JOB_NAME or %SEARCHSTRING%" i
    {
    awk -v dbg="${DBG}" \
        -v noval="${NOVAL}" \
        -v header="${HEADER}" \
        -v format="${FORMAT}" \
        -v splitter="${SPLITTER}" '\
    BEGIN{
        k=0 ;
        altSplit=0 ;
        switch (noval) {
            case "NL" : { noval="NULL" ;    break ; } ;
            case "SP" : { noval=" " ;       break ; } ;
            default :   { noval="" ;        break ; } ;
        } ;
    }{
        k++
        if(dbg == 1 ){ print "\n", k, "\nLINE= ", $0  | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        pos=index( $0, ":" ) ;
        field=substr( $0, 1, pos-1 ) ;
        if(dbg == 1 ){ print " >> field= ", field  | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        tmp=substr( $0, pos+2 ) ;
        gsub( "\"", "", tmp) ;

        if( index( tmp, "," ) != 0 ){ altSplit=1 ; } ;
        if(dbg == 1 ){ print " >> altSplit= ", altSplit  | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        if(dbg == 1 ){ print " >> tmp= ", tmp  | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        switch (field) {
            case "insert_job" : {
                #insert_job: JOB_B   job_type: CMD
                  jn=$2 ;
                  jt=$4 ;
                #Initialize other fields with empty string for placement
                 cmd=noval ;
                 mcn=noval ;
                 own=noval ;
                  dc=noval ;
                   c=noval ;
                  rc=noval ;
                  ec=noval ;
                 dow=noval ;
                 ruw=noval ;
                  st=noval ;
                  sm=noval ;
                prof=noval ;
                 trt=noval ;
                  wf=noval ;
                  wi=noval ;
                } ; break ;
            case "command" :        {  cmd=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "machine" :        {  mcn=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "owner" :          {  own=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "date_conditions" :    {   dc=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "condition" :      {    c=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "run_calendar" :       {   rc=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "exclude_calendar" :   {   ec=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "days_of_week" :       {  dow=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "run_window" :     {  ruw=tmp ; } ; break ;
            case "start_times" :        {   st=tmp ; } ; break ;
            case "start_mins" :     {   sm=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "profile" :        { prof=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "term_run_time" :      {  trt=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "watch_file" :     {   wf=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "watch_interval" :     {   wi=tmp  ; } ; break ;
            case "permission" :     break ;
            default:
                if( $0 != "" ){
                    printf("[WARNING|%s] Ignored line %s for NON-recognized field: %s\n", FILENAME, NR, field ) | "cat >&2" ;
                } ; break ;
        } ;
    }END{
        if( altSplit == 1 ){
            gsub( ",", splitter , header ) ;
            gsub( ",", splitter , format ) ;
        } ;

        print header ;

        printf(format, \
            jn, jt, cmd, mcn, own, dc, c, rc, ec, dow, ruw, st, sm, prof, trt, wf, wi ) ;
        }' "${job}" > "${DESTINATION}.csv"
        ls -l "${DESTINATION}.csv"
    } 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("\t%s\n", $0 ) ; }'

    echo -e "\nReviewing '${DESTINATION}.csv' ..."
    more  "${DESTINATION}.csv"
    echo ""
done
exit
```

The session log (with debugging turned off) is as follows:

```
ericthered:/0__WORK$ ./test_95.sh --empty --quotes
Processing: JOB_A ...
    [WARNING|JOB_A] Ignored line 7 for NON-recognized field: alarm_if_fail
    [WARNING|JOB_A] Ignored line 9 for NON-recognized field: alarm_if_terminated
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 337 Dec 20 20:23 DUMP__JOB_A.csv

Reviewing 'DUMP__JOB_A.csv' ...
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_cale
ndar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_int
erval"
"JOB_A","FW","","machine.server.com","User","0","","","","","","","","/tmp/.profile","3","/tmp/Control*","60"

Processing: JOB_B ...
    [WARNING|JOB_B] Ignored line 10 for NON-recognized field: std_out_file
    [WARNING|JOB_B] Ignored line 11 for NON-recognized field: std_err_file
    [WARNING|JOB_B] Ignored line 12 for NON-recognized field: alarm_if_fail
    [WARNING|JOB_B] Ignored line 13 for NON-recognized field: alarm_if_terminated
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 364 Dec 20 20:23 DUMP__JOB_B.csv

Reviewing 'DUMP__JOB_B.csv' ...
"insert_job"|"job_type"|"command"|"machine"|"owner"|"date_conditions"|"condition"|"run_calendar"|"exclude_cale
ndar"|"days_of_week"|"run_window"|"start_times"|"start_mins"|"profile"|"term_run_time"|"watch_file"|"watch_int
erval"
"JOB_B"|"CMD"|"Autorep -M ALL"|"machine.server.com"|"User"|"1"|""|""|""|"mo,tu,we,th,fr"|"06:00-19:00"|""|"9,1
9,29,39,49,59"|""|""|""|""

ericthered:/0__WORK$
```

As you can see above, the logic triggered the alternate delimiter "|" on detection of the **commas in data** for **JOB_B**.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```bash
sed -E '1s/[[:blank:]]+(job_type:)/\n\1/' "$file" \
| gawk '
    BEGIN {
        header = "insert_job,job_type,command,machine,owner,date_conditions,condition,run_calendar,exclude_calendar,days_of_week,run_window,start_times,start_mins,profile,term_run_time,watch_file,watch_interval"
        n = split(header, h, /,/)
    }
    match($0, /([[:alnum:]_]+): (.*)/, m) {
        field[m[1]] = gensub(/"/, "&&", "g", m[2])
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "\"%s\"%s", h[i], (i == n ? "\n" : ",")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "\"%s\"%s", field[h[i]], (i == n ? "\n" : ",")
    }
'
```

Outputs: JOB_A

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_A","FW","","machine.server.com","User","0","","","","","","","","""/tmp/.profile""","3","""/tmp/Control*""","60"
```

JOB_B

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_B","CMD","Autorep -M ALL","machine.server.com","User","1","","","","mo,tu,we,th,fr","""06:00-19:00""","","9,19,29,39,49,59","","","",""
```

This uses `sed` to split the 2 name:value pairs on line 1 into 2 separate lines. Then, every line can be parsed the same way.

I'm using GNU awk specifically: for the 3-argument match() function and the gensub() function.

One thing you need to be aware of with CVS: embedded quotes need to be doubled. To put `He said "hello."` as a CSV field would look like

```
"sentence"
"He said ""hello."""
```

That's what I'm doing with the `gensub` function.

---

I assume you'll want to put multiple jobs in the same CSV output. You can do this:

```bash
to_csv() {
    sed -E '1s/[[:blank:]]+(job_type:)/\n\1/' "$1" \
    | gawk '
        BEGIN {
            header = "insert_job,job_type,command,machine,owner,date_conditions,condition,run_calendar,exclude_calendar,days_of_week,run_window,start_times,start_mins,profile,term_run_time,watch_file,watch_interval"
            n = split(header, h, /,/)
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                printf "\"%s\"%s", h[i], (i == n ? "\n" : ",")
        }
        BEGINFILE {delete field}
        match($0, /([[:alnum:]_]+): (.*)/, m) {
            field[m[1]] = gensub(/"/, "&&", "g", m[2])
        }
        ENDFILE {
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                printf "\"%s\"%s", field[h[i]], (i == n ? "\n" : ",")
        }
    '
}

for file in JOB_*; do
    to_csv "$file"
done \
| awk 'NR == 1 || NR % 2 == 0'
```

which outputs

```
"insert_job","job_type","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"JOB_A","FW","","machine.server.com","User","0","","","","","","","","""/tmp/.profile""","3","""/tmp/Control*""","60"
"JOB_B","CMD","Autorep -M ALL","machine.server.com","User","1","","","","mo,tu,we,th,fr","""06:00-19:00""","","9,19,29,39,49,59","","","",""
```